# Checkbox misaligned in mobile view

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-design-system

I have a table which I am showing stacked in the mobile view.

I have a checkbox input to show an indicator, it looks alright in desktop view, however gets misaligned in the mobile view.

I have tried applying slds-align-top class, but it didn't work,
I have also tried using variant="label-hidden", it didn't work.

```
<table class="slds-table slds-no-row-hover slds-table_striped slds-table_fixed-layout slds-max-medium-table_stacked-horizontal">
                            <thead>
                                <tr class="slds-text-title_caps">
                                    <th>
                                    </th>
                                    <th>
                                        <div class="slds-truncate" title="Column 1">Quote Id</div>
                                    </th>
                                    <th>
                                        <div class="slds-truncate" title="Column 2">Quote Description</div>
                                    </th>
                                    <th>
                                        <div class="slds-truncate" title="Column 3">Created On</div>
                                    </th>
                                    <th>
                                        <div class="slds-truncate" title="Column 4">View</div>
                                    </th>
                                    <th>
                                        <div class="slds-truncate" title="Column 5">Is Accepted?</div>
                                    </th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <aura:iteration indexVar="index" items="{!v.listQuotes}" var="quote">
                                    <tr aura:id="{!quote.Id}">
                                        <td>
                                            <lightning:input aura:id="chkbox" checked="{!quote.checked}" id="{!quote.Id}" type="checkbox" onchange="{!c.checkboxSelect}" disabled="{!v.isQuoteAccepted}" variant="label-hidden"/>
                                        </td>
                                        <td data-label="Quote Number">
                                            <div id="{!index}" class="slds-text-title slds-text-color_default">{!quote.Name}</div>
                                        </td>
                                        <td data-label="Description">
                                            <div id="{!index}" class="slds-text-title slds-text-color_default">{!quote.Desc}</div>
                                        </td>
                                        <td data-label="Created On">
                                            <div id="{!index}" class="slds-text-title slds-text-color_default">{!quote.CreatedOn}</div>
                                        </td>
                                        <td data-label="View Quote">
                                            <lightning:button name="{!quote.Id}" variant="base" label="View" title="View" onclick="{!c.viewQuote}"/>
                                        </td>
                                        <td data-label="Is Accepted?">
                                         <lightning:input checked="{!quote.IsAccepted}" type="checkbox" disabled="true" variant="label-hidden"/>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </aura:iteration>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
```

[image: Mobile View]

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend using `table` for layout purposes. Considering looking into Form Elements [(SLDS Documentation)](https://lightningdesignsystem.com/components/form-element/#Horizontal) or `variant="label-inline"` on your `lightning:input`.